# How do I see CiviCRM variables in Netbeans using xDebug?

Tags: civicase, xdebug

I'm trying to use Netbeans and xDebug to read some CiviCRM variables, but I am thus far unable to even see any CiviCRM variables in Netbeans. xDebug (version 3) does seem to be connecting to Netbeans without issue, and showing me the HTTP-related variables such as cookies and contents of GET and POST requests.

When I open a case in CiviCRM, I don't see any CiviCRM-specific variables, although I do see some new HTTP and PHP variables. How do I go about finding the CiviCRM variables that I need to read?

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini make sure [xdebug.mode](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode) has "debug" in it. In netbeans set breakpoints in the code, so e.g. for opening Manage Case set a breakpoint in [CRM/Case/Form/CaseView](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/f063ffda5d2e60a8b0bf6abf2dfe26e53bb699c8/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php#L80). Then it will pause execution and you can examine the variables.